# ¿Por qué hay un "segmentation fault" en fscanf?

Tags: c

Dado el siguiente **código**, que es parte de un programa más grande.

```
/*Retorna cero si ya no hay más que leer*/
int leer (FILE *file, lista_notas *inicio, lista_notas *final){
        /*Nota  leída*/
        int nota;
        char *delimitador = " ";
        /*Si ya no hay más que leer, se acabó el fichero*/
        int res;
        /*Auxiliar para leer la primera linea, pues conocemos el formato de los tres datos
        pero no cuántos espacios en blanco hay entre cada dato*/
        char *linea;
        if( (res = fscanf(file,"%s%d",linea,&nota)) ){/*Cuerpo*/}
        /*Más código irrelevante para el caso*/
}
```

Me informa el compilador de un ***segmentation fault*** que, mediante depuración con gdb, se especifica que dicho error está **en la función fscanf**:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00007ffff7e4c88c in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=s@entry=0x555555559260, format=, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffe820, errp=errp@entry=0x0)
at vfscanf.c:1100

1100    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.

Parece ser que el argumento **&nota es erróneo, ¿por qué?** He probado a introducir una variable entera inicializada previamente (int nota = 5) y tampoco. Según el código de error, la entrada **&nota es la dirección cero**, pero no entiendo por qué está el sistema asignando esa dirección a "nota".

El programa original se encarga de comprobar que **el fichero es correcto** para que este se pueda leer sin problemas. El contenido del fichero también es correcto al igual que todos los datos que el programa maneja hasta llegar a esta función llamada "leer". En definitiva, **el fallo tiene que estar obligatoriamente en la sección de código compartida**.

El formato para cada línea del fichero de entrada es: Nombre [n espacios en blanco] Apellido [n espacios en blanco] nota

¿Qué está sucediendo? Gracias.

Comment: Creo que el problema no es `&nota`, sino `linea` que has declarado como un `char*` pero no has inicializado, por lo que apunta a no se sabe dónde (o a NULL, depende del compilador). Por otro lado `fscanf()`, no puede leer cadenas si contienen espacios (se detiene en el primer espacio) por lo que no puedes usarlo para leer "Nombre Apellido". Yo usaría `fgets()` para leer la línea completa (con nota y todo), a un buffer de un tamaño pre-declarado, y luego ya procesaría letra a letra ese buffer para separar nombre, apellido y nota, y usaría `atoi()` o `sscanf()` para leer la nota.

Comment: También probé a inicializar "linea" con un calloc, pero el fallo persistía. De hecho, la línea de error de gdb muestra claramente que el último parámetro de fscanf es erróneo. Claro que también soy nuevo en esto de la depuración en C. Mañana probaré de nuevo, más fresco, por si acaso. También seguiré el consejo de emplear fgets. El viernes os comentaré cómo me fue todo. Gracias.

Comment: No, la línea de error muestra que es erróneo el último parámetro de `_IO_vfscanf_internal()` y no de `fscanf()`. La función que produce el error es una interna a la que `fscanf()` llama. O quizás `fscanf()` no sea más que una macro que se expande a otra cosa. Yo no me fiaría de ese mensaje de error, y en todo caso el puntero 0x0 que se ve en ese mensaje se refiere a un parámetro llamado `errp` que no puede ser tu `&nota` porque `fscanf()` recibe un número variable de parámetros que por tanto no tienen nombre.

Comment: Ya se solucionó el problema, aunque me surgió otro muy curioso con un entero. Lo he recreado en un programa muy sencillo de unas 10 líneas. Lo publicaré hoy mismo, por si les interesa. No logro entender por qué se produce (es un problema que en Java, mi primer lenguaje, nunca me ha surgido). En cuanto a este, ABUFALIA debería escribir la respuesta para poder puntuarla. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Vale, ya no escribiré la pregunta que comentaba más arriba. El fallo se debe a que el paso de tipos básicos en C es por valor y no por referencia (por eso en Java no me pasaba). Me he dado cuenta mientras escribía la propia pregunta.

Comment: Ok Sergio, ya he escrito una respuesta donde me he extendido un poco más que en los comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error te ha enviado por una falsa pista. Si te fijas, la función que está produciendo error no es `fscanf()`, sino `_IO_vfscanf_internal()`, que se conoce que es una función interna invocada desde `fscanf()`.

El puntero 0x0 que se ve en ese mensaje de error se refiere a un parámetro llamado `errp` que sugiere por el nombre tratarse de un puntero a un *stream* de errores. En cualquier caso no puede tratarse de tu parámetro `&nota` porque al ser `fscanf()` una función *variádica* (recibe un número variable de argumentos), estos argumentos no tienen posiciones fijas en el prototipo, ni nombre.

Un sospechoso más plausible para causar un *segfault* es el puntero `linea` que has declarado como un `char*` pero no has inicializado, por lo que apunta a no se sabe dónde (o a NULL, dependiendo del compilador).

Ese parámetro debería mejor ser un array de tamaño fijo, por ejemplo `char linea[200]`, si bien el tamaño tienes que ponerlo asegurándote de que nunca vas a encontrar líneas más largas de ese valor.

Esto es un riesgo de seguridad, pues si una línea tuviera una longitud mayor, `fscanf()` de todas formas seguirá leyendo caracteres y guardándolos en memoria, más allá de la terminación de ese array, sobreescribiendo posiblemente otras variables y causando un comportamiento indefinido.

Además, `fscanf()` con la cadena de formato `"%s"` no puede leer cadenas que contengan espacios (se detiene al encontrar el primer espacio), por lo que no es una buena elección para leer líneas o para leer "Nombre Apellidos".

Yo usaría `fgets()` para leer la línea completa (con nota y todo), a un buffer de un tamaño pre-declarado. `fgets()` tiene la ventaja de que le puedes especificar como parámetro el tamaño del buffer y nunca leerá más caracteres de los que caben en el mismo.

Una vez tengas la línea leída en un buffer, se procesaría letra a letra ese buffer para separar nombre, apellido y nota (tambén puedes usar `strtok()` para separar en trozos por el espacio, pero esa función tiene una forma de usarse muy confusa). Para convertir la parte de la nota en entero podrás usar `atoi()`.

Otra opción una vez tengas la línea completa es usar `sscanf()` para separar los valores que quieras leer de esa línea. Por ejemplo puedes usar la cadena de formato `"%s %s %d"` para separar "Nombre", "Apellido" (como cadenas) y "edad" (como entero), pero esto sólo funcionará correctamente si efectivamente la línea contiene esos tres campos separados por espacios y son del tipo correcto.